# How to update application code in google compute engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, mean-stack

I have installed the Google MEAN(MongoDB, Express, AngularJs and NodeJS) Stack in my Compute Engine VM (Virtual Machine) by using this following link

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mean/

and I successfully run the sample app you can test it

```
 http://146.148.94.102:3000
```

But i don't now where the sample code is located and how I can replace that sample code with my application code.

Please let me know how to do it this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [Folder structure](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#folder-structure) for MEAN. In your new instance, there's a folder created in /opt/. If you use the default name, this should be in /opt/myApp.